# Why is "Samsung Push Service" using so much of my battery?

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-ace-plus

Looking at the battery usage summary on my Galaxy Ace Plus (GT-S7500), I found that "Samsung Push Service" (v1.0.4) has used 29% of my battery. I'm having problems with the battery not lasting very long (about 1 day mostly on standby), so anything that extends the time a charge lasts will be valuable.

What does the "Samsung Push Service" do? Should I uninstall it (I never chose to install it, so it must have been on the phone to start with), or is there another way to reduce it's battery usage?

Edit: When drilling down into the Samsung Push Service from battery usage, I see that is keeping my phone permanently awake. This doesn't seem sensible!

Comment: You won't be able to uninstall it as it's most likely a system app. You could try going to *settings->apps->manage apps* if you can find and disable it. This way you a) get rid of its running service, and b) can re-enable it anytime if needed (e.g. if you find out some other apps depend on it, and the system starts behaving strangely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't stop it (or do anything at all) from Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All -> Samsung Push Service.

I opened "Samsung Apps" and it prompted me to upgrade. After that had completed, I went to Settings -> About Phone -> Battery Usage -> Samsung Push Service and chose Force Stop, as it still seemed to be running heavily.

Upon powering the phone off and on, the App started up again, but no longer keeps the phone awake. I see it's now running version 1.1.4, which may have fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally downloaded the Push Service and, as I haven't a clue what it is for, I followed the instructions in this forum and it seems to have uninstalled. Possibly, I'm mistaken but it is worth a try.